# What's a reporting solution that can export PDF's at the content height, not page height?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, crystal-reports, reporting, telerik-reporting

I need to generate a report that programmatically (C#) exports to PDF at the height of the reports content (not a predefined page height). Width of the report should be fixed.

I've tried SSRS, CrystalReports XI (older version) and Telerik Reporting, but so far haven't been able to get the results I want.

Has any one been able to accomplish this using one of those solutions? Is there another solution that could do what I'm asking?

tl;dr

I'm building an internal LOB app that involves a lot of different phone and tablet devices. To unify printing, I built a Windows Service that accepts PDF's and can send them to a printer. We have a receipt printer with a continuous roll. If the PDF we're printing is properly constrained (one page with the exact height of the content), the receipt printer works great.

At one point I explored the option of creating the report as a HTML page. The Chrome browser will honor the @page css when saving as PDF. I was able to dynamically set the height of the @page css to match the height of the document. This produced a correctly sized PDF, but I can't seem to automate the PDF generation via C#. I looked into [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) with [CEFSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), but it fails to offer any PDF export (printing using CEF shows a print dialog and is not headless, which is a requirement of mine). The project [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) looked promising, but even with the `--print-media-type` switch, it seems to ignore the @page css.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
@media print {
    /* css code to make page height equal to content height*/
}
```